# See day agenda while scheduling tasks?

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

Assuming that I have TODO entries, most of which I have set the EFFORT property in a standard way (i.e. one of "0:15 0:30 1:00 2:00 3:00 4:00"), is there a way to schedule these tasks automatically over the coming days - say starting now or starting tomorrow - assuming also that there is some way of setting, say "no more than 6 hours per day"? (to leave time for other smaller tasks)

Ideally the order of the tasks in time would be the same as they would be listed in an agenda.

The reason I want this is that I would like to be able to tell someone "Yes, I can do that for you but not until Thurs 6 Nov", for example.

RETHINK:

If I put an effort against a single TODO, can I automatically schedule that task AFTER all the existing scheduled tasks - again assuming that no more than 6 hours of scheduled work will get done on one day?

UPDATE:

What I want is to schedule tasks manually, on days, with an easy way of knowing what is already scheduled on a day before I hit enter.

It is possible, when using `C-c` `C-s` to see the other tasks scheduled on a day before I press enter? This way I can schedule tasks on days that are not already full. Not automatic like my original idea, but 90% of what I want. Ideally the display of the day would update as I use the arrows to move around the calendar.

Comment: What does "...AFTER all the existing scheduled tasks" mean in the context of SCHEDULED tasks that repeat? You may not have any but they do exist so you need to worry about them, otherwise a naive "give me the next date available for scheduling" may return a date infinitely far into the future :-)

Comment: You make a good point: I've re-thought the whole thing again. Question updated.

Comment: You can get a daily agenda for today and keep hitting `f` to look at the agenda for subsequent days until you find one that's empty enough for your purposes. Then `C-c C-s` for that date. Is that good enough?